# Dynamically change the value of a label in accordance with the value of the textbox c# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

Here I want to insert some value in present payment and the value of due will be changed according to the value dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add an event handler to the textbox `TextChanged` event and then use this to update label text

```
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```

and then in `textBox1_TextChanged`

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = textBox1.Text + " In label";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an event to the TextBox's `TextChanged` even that updates the Label's Text

```
//assuming myTextBox and myLabel
myTextBox.TextChanged += myTextBox_TextChanged;

void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myLabel.Content = myTextBox.Text;
    }
```